# Login to Google+ opens Safari using Google+ iOS Api

Tags: ios, iphone, google-api, google-plus

I got rejected by Apple with this reason:

[image]

And my question is:

How can I avoid from sending the user to `Safari` when "Sign in with Google+" button pressed?

This behavior provide and determine by `Google+ Api` as far as I know.

Comment: Have a look at [issue 900](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=900#c109).

Comment: @abraham It works, please add your own answer and I'll get it. Thanks m8!